# Appending new values to a python list

Tags: python, list, find

Lets say I have two lists:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,7,8]
```

I want to append to x any values in y that are not already in x.  I can do this easily with a loop:

```
for value in y:
    if value not in x:
        x.append(value)
```

But I am wondering if there a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [22]: x = [1,2,3,4]

In [23]: y = [1,4,7,8]

In [24]: x += [ item for item in y if item not in x]

In [25]: x
Out[25]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

`+=` acts as `list.extend`, so the above code is equivalent to :

```
In [26]: x = [1,2,3,4]

In [27]: lis = [ item for item in y if item not in x]

In [28]: x.extend(lis)

In [29]: x
Out[29]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

> Note that if the size of list `x` is huge and your list x/y contain
>   only immutable(hashable) items then you must use `sets` here, as they
>   will improve the time complexity to `O(N)`.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is an O(n**2), if x and y are small that's probably ok. On the other hand if you find this too slow you might want to pick an algorithm that leverages sorting the elements of x/y or uses sets or dictionaries.

Comment: @BiRico Using `sets`/dictionaries means x/y must contain only `hashable` values and sorting will affect the order.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> y = [1,4,7,8]
>>> set_x = set(x) # for fast O(1) amortized lookup
>>> x.extend(el for el in y if el not in set_x)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did not care about the order of the result you could do:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>>> y=[1,4,7,8]
>>> x = list(set(x + y))
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: -1 removes duplicates from x, and adds the (unnecessary) restriction that elements must be hashable

Comment: @wim on the other hand if the elements are hashable and x/y do not have any duplicates you get an O(n) method with no downside. It's all about use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,7,8]
```

Now we want to append to x any values in y that are not already in x. This can be done easily as:

```
temp = [item for item in y if item not in x]
x.extend(temp)
```

This will first put all the elements which are not in x but are present in y in a list called temp. Now we shall extend list x to include elements from temp. Hope it helps.